# mental math: approximating fractional exponents

Tags: exponentiation, education, mental-arithmetic

Does anyone have any good tricks for estimating expressions with fractional exponents (besides guess and check)?

For example, I want to easily calculate $9.1^{1/3}$.  Currently, the best I've got is trial and error, but besides that $2^3 = 8$ and $3^3 = 27$, it gets pretty ugly...   Could I approximately interpolate between these two?

Comment: Would  "2 and a little more"  be too crude an approximation?

Comment: If you are serious about mental arithmetic you have undoubtedly memorized tables of cubes up $21^3=9261$, and can interpolate between $\root3\of8=2$ and $\root3\of{9.261}=2.1$ :-)

Comment: You may want to check out [Manny Sardina's _General Method for Extracting Roots Using (Folded) Continued Fractions_](http://www.myreckonings.com/Dead_Reckoning/Online/Materials/General%20Method%20for%20Extracting%20Roots.pdf), although that method works better for integers.

Answer (score 4):

Using calculus, specifically [Taylor approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series), centered at 8 (which is the closest value to 9.1 whose cube root we know), we get $$(8+x)^{1/3}=2+\frac{1}{12}x-\frac{1}{288}x^2+\frac{5}{20736}x^3\cdots$$
Hence, in your example, we have $x=1.1$, or $$(8+1.1)^{1/3}=2+\frac{1}{12}1.1-\frac{1}{288}1.1^2+\frac{5}{20736}1.1^3\cdots$$
You can compute as many terms as you need.  One term givs you 2.  Two terms gives you $2.091\overline{6}$.  Three terms gives you $2.0874652\overline{7}$.

Comment: Thanks!  Can you remind me of the generalized form for binomials?

Answer (score 2):

Use one step Newton formula for the zero of $f(x) = x^3-a\;$ with $a=9.1\;$ and the starting value $x_0 = 2$
$$x_1 = x_0 - \frac{f(x_0)}{f'(x_0)}= 2 - \frac{2^3-9.1}{2\times2^2}
= 2 + \frac{1.1}{12} = 2 + \frac{1}{10}\frac{110}{120} \\
x_1\approx 2 + \frac{1}{10}\frac{108}{120} = 2 + \frac{9}{100} = 2.09
$$

Comment: Thanks!  Can you explain briefly how you're constructing $f(x)$?

Comment: This is the function for cube roots $x^3=a\;$ and you want to find a zero of $x^3-a=0\;$ thus $f(x)=x^3-a$